# How can I ask the NLTK to have synonyms be connected to nearby terms, rather than an island?

Tags: nlp, nltk, wordnet

I am working on an NLTK project, intended in principle to be like a standard thesaurus but (quasi-)continuous. To take one example, there are dozens of entries connected with books, including both religious classics and ledgers.

I tried fiddling with some terms, but I seemed to get just a smaller slice of the pie by doing that. (A "ledger" result contained "daybook" but the substances was a much smaller collection than one would find by reading a book.) The discussion of "synsets" in the documentation seem to imply both that you can find terms close to an existing terms, but the synsets are like islands, or see such to me.

What (if any) means are there to say something like "I want all words with a high match score above XYZ threshold" or "I want to match the n closest related terms." The documentation looks like this is possible, with a really nice way of calculating a proximity score between two words, but  don't see how to adjust the threshold or alternately how to request the n closest matches.

What are my best bets here?

Comment: Hm I don't really follow your project. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you just looking for (near)synonyms?

Comment: I'm trying to do something like [Visual Thesaurus](https://www.visualthesaurus.com/). In other words, you start with one term, and you can navigate to other terms with increasingly different meanings. The equivalent for roads and terrain is that you can drive on paved roads and go from the state of Washington to Florida, or California to New York, traversing only paved roads (no Jeep 4x4 needed). Imagine a much sparser graph of roads where Illinois roads wouldn't take you out, and there were actually only two or three connected components. (Can you see why I'd like a much denser graph?)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to compute distance between arbitrary pairs of words, WordNet is the wrong tool for the job: It is a network of particular terms, so either there is a path between two nodes or there is not. Look around for corpus-based measures instead.

A quick google gave [this thread](https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-popular-ready-to-use-tools-to-compute-semantic-similarity-between-two-words) (not on SO) that could serve as a starting point.

In the nltk, I would start by taking a look at [`nltk.text.ContextIndex`](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/text.html#ContextIndex), which seems to be behind the nltk demo function `nltk.Text.similar()`. It won't calculate distances between pairs of words, but at least you'll have a rich network of contexts you can start from.

```
>>> contexts = nltk.text.ContextIndex(nltk.corpus.brown.words()[:100000])
>>> contexts.similar_words("fact")
['jury', 'announcement', 'Washington', 'addition', '1961', 'impression', 
'news', 'belief', 'commissioners', 'Laos', 'return', '1959', '1960', '1956',
'result', 'University', 'opinion', 'work', 'course', 'hope']
```

I'll leave it to you to remove punctuation, stopwords etc. I haven't looked at the algorithms behind this, but you can always implement your own favorite algorithm if this doesn't do the job for you.

Comment: Hmm, so some of my worries are confirmed. The documentation [example](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html) seems to offer multiple similarity options that should address this. Are there other tools you'd recommend for the project?

Comment: I don't have any experience with this, so no.